# $.css('-ms-transform') not working

Tags: jquery

For some magical reason it seems that jQuery won't add the -ms-transform to my element. Is there a specific reason for this to happen?

Also tried with: `$('#img').attr('-ms-transform', 'matrix..');` but no luck.

Anybody know why?

Comment: There's no such html attribute as `-ms-tranform`. It's a CSS property.

Comment: Have you tried `$('#img').css('-ms-transform', 'matrix..');`

Comment: Sorry @Pankucins, it should be added in the style html attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give it a try using the camel-case versión of the property without '-'

```
$('#img').css('msTransform', 'matrix..');
```

Hope it works